# State variable shows value 'undefined' though have set default value 'false'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state, react-state-management

I created a custom component `MyCustomList` which is just a wrapper of `FlatList`. There are three props `items`, `getMore`, `loading`. This post focuses on the passed in `loading` prop only.

```
const MyCustomList = ({items, getMore, loading}) => {
      // console shows 'false'
      console.log(loading) 
      
      // use the 'loading' as the default value for the state variable
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(loading);

      const myFooter = () => {
           // console shows undefined, why? Shouldn't it be the default value 'false'?
           console.log(isLoading});
            ...
      }
      return (
          <FlatList
            keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
            data={items}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            onEndReached={getMore}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
            ListFooterComponent={myFooter}
    />
  );
  ...
  export default MyCustomList;
}
```

In above custom component, parent component passed in the `loading` prop with value `false`, at runtime when swipe the list to bottom, the myFooter is called but the state variable `isLoading` is logged with value `undefined`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below, we setting the `isLoading` state in `useEffect`

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';//add
 
 const MyCustomList = ({items, getMore, loading}) => {
           // console shows 'false'
           console.log(loading) 
           
           // use the 'loading' as the default value for the state variable
           const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(loading);
     
           useEffect(() => {
             setIsLoading(loading)
            }, []);
 
           const myFooter = () => {
                // console shows undefined, why? Shouldn't it be the default value 'false'?
                console.log(isLoading});
                 ...
           }
           return (
               <FlatList
                 keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                 data={items}
                 renderItem={renderItem}
                 onEndReached={getMore}
                 onEndReachedThreshold={0}
                 ListFooterComponent={myFooter}
         />
       );
       ...
       export default MyCustomList;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

change to this only

```
const MyCustomList = ({items, getMore, loading = false}) => {
```

....